# Android App works in debug but doesn't work in release mode

Tags: android, cordova

My app loads and connects to server fine when running through `Android Studio` in debug mode. When I create a signed `APK` for release, the app loads, but when it gets to the point where it communicates with API server is doesn't connect. 
I watch the logs on server side and it doesn't connect, but when run through `Android Studio`, it does connect.

Is there anyway to debug this release version? I have tried to use `chrome://inspect`, but that only finds the browser.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I think your api is in localhost...

Comment: Yea, checked that. API is hosted on Azure. When I run through Android Studio on device, I get server logs on Azure. So I know that Android Studio version is hitting remote server.

Comment: maybe different url set in build.gradle for release and debug ?

Comment: I've checked the build.gradle and I don't see anything like that. Is there some place where I should be looking?

Comment: Are you using https? your device probably doesn't trust your server certificate

Answer (score 0):

This is an app using Phonegap and Android. The back end is HTTPS. In order for your to hit the backend with HTTPS in Android Chrome, you have to add the intermediate certificates on your server. Once you add those, everything worked fine for me.

Comment: can you give more details? Do you know if this can be done with aws elastic load balancer? Is there a way to diagnose??